# canvas loadFromJson does not apply font-family

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am using below code to render google font and update the canvas:

```
    /* on change of font load the preview as well as canvas */
    $('#font').on('change', function () {
        $('.font_preview').show();
        var font_family = $(this).val();

        $('.font_preview').css('font-family', font_family, 14);
        $('.font_preview').html(font_family,'');
        load_web_font([font_family],'.font_preview',font_family,1);
    });

    function load_web_font(font_family, preview_div,font_family_text,preview_text) {
        var grep_font = jQuery.grep(font_family, function (n, i) {
            return ( n );
        });
        if (grep_font.length > 0) {
            var preview_text;
            if (preview_div) {
                preview_text = $(preview_div).text();
            }
            WebFont.load({
                google: {
                    families: font_family
                },
                fontloading: function (familyName, fvd) {
                    if (preview_div) {
                        if(preview_text==1)
                        {
                            $(preview_div).text('font loading ... ');
                        }
                    }

                },
                fontactive: function (familyName, fvd) {
                    if (preview_div) {
                        if(preview_text==1)
                        {
                            $(preview_div).text(preview_text);
                        }
                        load_font_on_canvas(font_family_text);
                    }
                },
                timeout: 10000
            });
        }
    }

     //Load Font on Canvas
    function load_font_on_canvas(font_style)
    {
        var font_style = font_style;
        if(font_style=='')
        {
            alert('Please select a Font Style');
            return false;
        }
        var tObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
        //Check that text is selected
        if(tObj==undefined)
        {
            alert('Please select a Text');
            return false;
        }
        tObj.set({
            fontFamily: font_style
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
```

Now, i am storing canvas data as a json in DB. So after that when ever user will try to edit that canvas, i am rendering the canvas using below code:

```
    if(is_update==1) // Update then load the card
    {
        // parse the data into the canvas
        canvas1.loadFromJSON(front_side_object);
        // re-render the canvas
        canvas1.renderAll();

        canvas2.loadFromJSON(back_side_object);
        canvas2.renderAll();
    }
```

So canvas is loading, but not with the fonts which user have selected. So i have tried below code to update canvas with google fonts but its not working

```
    //Grab each google fonts
    var all_fonts = [];
    $('#font option').each(function(){
        var font_family = $(this).val();
        //all_fonts +=  font_family + '|';
        if(font_family!='')
        {
            all_fonts.push(font_family);
        }
    });
    load_all_web_font(all_fonts);

    function load_all_web_font(all_fonts)
    {
        var grep_font = jQuery.grep(all_fonts, function (n, i) {
            return ( n );
        });
        WebFont.load({
            google: {
                families: all_fonts
            },
            fontloading: function (familyName, fvd) {
                //Do Something
            },
            fontactive: function (familyName, fvd) {
                //1st Try rerender canvas again after fonts is loaded
                //Do SOmething
                canvas1.loadFromJSON(front_side_object);
                // re-render the canvas
                canvas1.renderAll();

                canvas2.loadFromJSON($model->back_side_object);
                canvas2.renderAll();

                //Get the text and rerender the canvas
                canvas1.getObjects().filter(function(o) {
                    if (o.get('type') === 'text') {
                        console.log(o.get);
                        canvas1.renderAll();
                    }
                });
                canvas2.getObjects().filter(function(o) {
                    if (o.get('type') === 'text') {
                        canvas2.renderAll();
                    }
                });
            },
            timeout: 10000
        });
    }
```

Comment: You have to check if google font is downloaded before loadFromJson. You can call renderAll again after finish loading google font.

Comment: @artgb I have done that in fontactive: function (familyName, fvd) { event. Once font is loaded i am calling renderAll.

Comment: Please make jsfiddle, difficult to expect current status.

Comment: there is a custom font load demo here: http://fabricjs.com/loadfonts it uses FontFaceObserver https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to first filter all text object & then load fonts and then render canvas.

This works for me

```
 let fonts = this.canvas
            .getObjects()
            .filter(o => o.get('type') === 'textbox')
            .map(o => o.fontFamily)

      WebFontLoader.load({
        google: {
          families: [...fonts],
        },
        active: () => {
          this.canvas.renderAll()
        },
      })
```

Comment: Thx for this answer. However `.filter((o: any)` is outputted in my vscode as not valid javascript. Would you be so kind to rewrite it? Thx!

Comment: @Carol.Kar I'm glad it's helpful. Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the code from typescript to javascript. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old problem but I had the same problem. What you need to do is to set the Text's `dirty` property to true, and then call `canvas.renderAll()`.

An example (in TypeScript) for what I used, is to call my function `rerenderWhenAFontisLoaded` after loading the JSON:

```js
import FontFaceObserver from 'fontfaceobserver';

const myFonts = ['Pacifico', 'VT323', 'Quicksand'];

const rerenderWhenAFontIsLoaded = (): void => {
    let timer: NodeJS.Timeout | null = null;
    myFonts.forEach((font) => {
        new FontFaceObserver(fontName)
        .load()
        .then(() => {
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = null;
            }
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                const [fonts] = getObjectsOfTypes(canvas, [['textbox', 'i-text', 'text']]);
                fonts.forEach((font) => {
                    font.dirty = true;
                });
                canvas.requestRenderAll();
            }, 1000);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            // dont care
        });
    });
};

/**
 * An recursive function to return an array of objects as defined in the types argument.
 * @param object Either an canvas or a group object
 * @param types: like [['polygon'], [['i-text', 'textbox', 'text']]
 * @returns array of fabric.Objects in the same order as you defined in the types argument.
 */
const getObjectsOfTypes = (object: fabric.Object | fabric.Canvas, types: string[][]): fabric.Object[][] => {
    const result: fabric.Object[][] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        result.push([]);
        if (types[i].includes((object as fabric.Object).type!)) {
            result[i].push(object as fabric.Object);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Check if we can call getObjects, then we either know it's the canvas or another group.
    if (typeof (object as fabric.Group).getObjects === 'function') {
        (object as fabric.Group | fabric.Canvas).getObjects().forEach((object) => {
            const moreRelevantObjects = this.getObjectsOfType(object, types);
            moreRelevantObjects.forEach((objects, i) => {
                result[i].push(...objects);
            });
        });
    }

    return result;
};
```